# SSIS add multiple command lines in a com application process task argument

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with my SSIS process task. I want to get file(s) from a sftp site with winscp.

I use the winscp.com application and when fill in the following arguments manually, it works fine.

```
open sftp:\username:password@ftp.site.com hostkey="ssh 1024 00:00:00"
get *.csv H:\Transfer
close 
exit
```

Now I like to automate this process in a SSIS task using a process task.

I put the following argument in a evaluated expression and added it as an argument in a process task

```
"sftp://" +  (DT_WSTR, 100)  @[User::ftpUsername]  + ":" +  (DT_WSTR,100) @[User::ftpPassword]  + "@" + (DT_WSTR,100) @[User::ftpSite]  + " -hostkey=" + (DT_WSTR, 100) @[User::sshKey]  + "\r \n"+ " get *.csv " + @[User::DownloadDirectory] + "\r \n"  + " close"+ "\r \n" + " exit " + "\r \n"
```

When I execute this task the following happens.. (see image)

[SSIS process task execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hB6H.jpg)

The automatic login works, but it doesn't go to the next command that get the csv files from the sftp site to the H:\Transfer folder and it does not close the session.

How can I make the SSIS process task arguments from an evaulated expression to go to the next command line?

Please help!

Comment: I fix it with a bat file, but still like to know if it is possible in a argument

Comment: try add `option batch continue` ahead? or either `off`,`abort`,`on`, depends on the specific feedback, I left the reference below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[For your reference](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option)

**batch off|on|abort|continue**

Enables batch mode. In batch mode, any choice prompt is automatically replied and any input prompt is cancelled (after short time interval). 
In batch mode, it is recommended to set confirm to off to allow overwrites. 
When batch mode is set to on any choice prompt is automatically replied negatively. Unless the prompt has a different default answer (such as a default “Reconnect” answer for a reconnect prompt), in what case the default answer is used (after a short time interval). See also a reconnecttime option below. 
Value abort is like on. In addition, the script is aborted, when any script command fails or any choice prompt is replied with “Abort” answer (or similar). 
When set to continue any choice prompt is automatically replied with “Skip”, “Ignore” or similar answer. 
Enabling batch mode sets reconnect time (reconnecttime option below) to 120 seconds, if it is not set yet. 
Commands affected: nearly all 
Default: abort for commands specified using /script or /command; off for commands specified on input.